# jquery each for form elements - how to get next, prev element in form?

Tags: jquery, forms, input, each

I have a form where each input element has a label with text and some labels have a span item with a class 'required', and there may be some more divs between the label and text inputs, e.g.

```
<label for="diameter">D<span class="required">Required</span></label>
<div ...
    <input type="text" id="diameter" name="diameter" value="20" />
```

I need to go through all inputs which have a label with the required span. I can spin through all the spans like

```
$('form .required').each(function(index, element) {
});
```

where the 'element' is the span. But how do I get the associated input? None of the below work:

```
element.next('input[type="text"]')
$(element).next('input[type="text"]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From its `for` attribute (accessible via `.attr` on jQuery or `.htmlFor` on the element), you can get the ID it points to, and with the ID, you can select the element you want:

```js
$('.required').each((_, span) => {
  const $input = $('#' + $(span).parent()[0].htmlFor);
  console.log($input.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="diameter">D<span class="required">Required</span></label>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="diameter" name="diameter" value="20">
</div>
```

If you're *required* to use `.next`, you can use:

```js
$('.required').each((_, span) => {
  const $span = $(span);
  const $parentLabel = $span.parent();
  const forVal = $parentLabel[0].htmlFor;
  const $input = $parentLabel.next('div').find('#' + forVal);
  console.log($input.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="diameter">D<span class="required">Required</span></label>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="diameter" name="diameter" value="20">
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but is there a more elegant way of getting the element from each so that I can use element.next()?

Comment: Using the `for` attribute is the most elegant general solution there is. If the input is always a descendant of the immediate next `div`, you could go to the next `div` and search in there too

Comment: It's stored in the `$input` variable in both snippets - whatever you need to do with them, you can do it with the `$input` variable name

Comment: how come console.log($(span).parent().next('input[type="text"]').val()); gives me 'undefined'?

Comment: The `input` is not a sibling of the parent - it's a *descendant* of the sibling of the parent. Another issue is that `input[type="text"]` may select *any* descendant input, not necessarily the one with the ID you want - if you want to go that route, save the `$parentLabel` in a variable first so you can extract its `for` attribute, then `.find` the right descendant.

Answer (score 2):

Since `span`  is inside `label` element, you can't directly use `next` method.

First you need to traverse to the parent element using `parent` method.

```
 $('form .required').each(function (index, element) {
     var inputElement = $(element).parent().next('div').find('input[type="text"]');
 });
```